# Simple MFC Application

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm currently in the process of learning MFC and GUI basics right now in my C++ class and I'm trying to create a really simple MFC program that has a green background and simply has text "Hello World" in the middle of the window. Unfortunately, it's become a difficult task for me to get anywhere past creating a plain-jane window with a title.

My question is, where do I begin to start changing the background color and adding text to the window. Where should I place this in my code?

here is what I have:

```
#include <afxwin.h>

class CMainFrame : public CFrameWnd
{
public:
    CMainFrame()
    {
        Create(NULL, _T("Windows App"));

    }
};
class CApp : public CWinApp
{
    CMainFrame *Frame;
    BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        Frame = new CMainFrame();
        m_pMainWnd = Frame;

        Frame->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
        Frame->UpdateWindow();


        return TRUE;
    }
};

CApp theApp;
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually one starts implementing a MFC application using the visual studio app wizard. It creates the initial application skeleton for you. That can be based on a simple dialog or on MFC document-view architecture. Setting the backgroud color is then done e.g. in the OnDraw() member function in the view class.

CMainframe is usually the main application window that contains the document windows and their views.

All that said, sghould you want to continue building this example, you can implement the OnPaint message handler: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01c9aaty.aspx and draw in there.

For this, you would also need to implement the message map in your window https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x0cx6b1.aspx and then add ON_WM_PAINT() handler. The app wizard also adds the message maps and handlers for you.

Comment: App wizard has its own issues. OP's code is better for learning MFC. Learning basic WinAPI programming is also useful.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: *"Learning basic WinAPI programming is also useful."* - No, not useful. It is **mandatory**.

Answer (score 0):

To change background color and to set text in window, first you have to handle WM_PAINT message handler. If you are using Visual studio IDE, then it can be done via selecting the message handler WM_PAINT in class wizard for CMainFrame class, else you can directly write handler code in implementation file. Below is code for your app:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CFrameWnd)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_SIZE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
void CMainFrame::OnPaint()
{
    CString strText = _T("Hello World");    //Display String
    TEXTMETRIC textMetricObj; //Structure to get height and width of char
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    CRect clientRect;
    CBrush brush;
    dc.GetTextMetrics(&textMetricObj);  //Get char height and width info
    int nCharHeight = textMetricObj.tmHeight;
    int nStrWidth = strText.GetLength() * textMetricObj.tmMaxCharWidth; // get max string width
    brush.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,255,0));   //create green brush to paint background color to green
    GetClientRect(&clientRect); // get active client area of window
    dc.FillRect(clientRect,&brush); //fill client area with green color
    //find display string bounding rectangle as middle of client window area
    int top = int((clientRect.Height() - nCharHeight) / 2);
    int bottom = int((clientRect.Height() + nCharHeight) / 2);
    int left = int((clientRect.Width() - nStrWidth) / 2);
    int right = int((clientRect.Width() + nStrWidth) / 2);
    dc.DrawText(strText,CRect(left,top,right,bottom),DT_CENTER);    //draw text in specified rectangle
}


void CMainFrame::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CFrameWnd::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);
    Invalidate();
}
```

I recommend you to go through book Programming Microsoft Visual C++ by David Kruglinski to understand the basics of MFC.